# SELECTing MySQL rows with unusual characters using PHP and querystrings

Tags: php, mysql

Table name Styles.
Referenced Column: Style

Coding with PHP 5.

Problem:
My SELECT query to MySQL returns 0 rows.

I'm using the column name in querystring as identifier (something like `example.com.php?style=paper-pencils`). For SEO purposes I've removed any odd characters and replaced spaces with '-'. Using url rewrite to end up with `example.com/paper-pencils`.

Working on a database I inherited which uses characters such as `'&'` or `':'` in the Style column. On the database side, the Style column would contain a row with something like `"Paper & Pencils"` as compared to my slugged version of "paper-pencils".

Things I've Tried:
I de-slug the url so i end up with 'paper pencils' (see below in query example).

I tried

```
SELECT * ,REPLACE( 'Style', '&', ' ' ) AS Style, REPLACE( 'Style', ':', ' ' ) AS Style FROM Styles
WHERE Style = 'paper pencils'
```

to no avail. The query I have runs fine, it just comes back with 0 results.

My next step would be to do a PHP SWITCH statement. Something like

```
case: $_GET['style'] = 'paper-pencils'
```

`$DBstyle = 'Paper & Pencils'` but I feel like there has to be some other way around it. I have 30 different possibilities and would prefer something better.

Any suggestions on how I can account for these unusual characters with random occurrences?

Comment: please give your table data then someone help you

Comment: please excuse my lack of erudition, i'm new to the site. how would i give my table data? you mean just a few rows or something like the schema? Here is an example: if i have a querystring:  example.com/george-m-bruestle i would query "george m bruestle". But i get nothing because what's in the database is actually George M. Bruestle (caps non-issue). If the querystring was example.com/leonardo-da-vinci I'd have no problem because i'm looking for leonardo da vinci where the actual data is Leonardo Da Vinci.  THanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add another column to this table called style_slug. This column will contain the slugged version that you use in your urls and will allow you to retrieve the Style column in your query.

Comment: I ended up creating an alternate table which references 1) the original table column name (where all the info is); and 2) the cleaned up slug. I however still have the same problem with another set of data. The problem is that a simple "SELECT * from tabl where "STYLES" = $styleNameFromQuerystring" will not sufice because i'm pooling from a database with names like Tom J. Johnson or Le-Miserables where things like '.' or '-' are not the norm but are definitely significant.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Gohn said or, a better one - use an approach which is used on this site - have both an unique identifier and a slug in the url.

```
example.com/2356356/paper-pencils
```

will cajole SEO and make your life easy.

Comment: I should have posted this on my original comment but your unique identifier idea was my first try. It caused some weird problems with an JQUERY .ajax function I had. For some reason I was getting my .ajax URL (e.g. load_info.php)as my unique parameter passed in querystring. So if my .ajax URL was 'load_info.php'...my querystring of example.com/1/paper-pencils was echoing load_info.php and paper-pencils respectively, rather than the intended "1" and "paper-pencils". Great idea though I just felt like I was going backwards there.

Comment: working on that presently. it's odd because the function works perfectly until i go from "^([\d\w-]+)$ index.php?styleName=$1 [L]" to "^([\d\w-]+)/([\d\w-]+)$ index.php?styleName=$1&StyleID=$2 [L]". You inspired me to start a new topic on that(being of course MY) ajax problem. Thank you for your assistance.